# UNIX: How to print out specific lines in a file using sed/awk/grep?

Tags: sorting, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a data in Unix which were fetched by a command and prints:

```
line01
line02
line03
line04
line05
line06
line07
line08
line09
line10
line11
line12
```

and I wanted to sort it out such that the lines 10 to 12 are above lines 1 to 9. like this:

```
line10
line11
line12
line01
line02
line03
line04
line05
line06
line07
line08
line09
```

i tried using

```
<command that fetches the data> | awk 'NR>=10 || NR<=9'
```

and

```
<command that fetches the data> | sed -n -e '4,5p' -e '1,3p'
```

but it still display in a sorted order. i'm new to unix so i don't know how to properly use awk/sed.

PS. These data are stored in a variable which will then be processed by another command. so i needed it to be sorted that way so that line 10-12 will be processed first. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1h;2,9H;1,9d;12G' file
```

Replace the hold space with line 1, then append lines 2 to 9 to the hold space and delete lines 1 thru 9. Print all other lines normally but on line 12 append the lines stored in the hold space to the pattern space.

Answer (score 3):

Use `head` and `tail`:

```
$ tail -n 2 file && head -n 3 file
name4
name5
name1
name2
name3
```

Your `awk` and `sed` approach do not work because you are just saying: print lines number X, Y and Z, and they will do so as soon as they find any of them. If you wanted to use these tools, you would need to read the file first, storing its content, and then print it.

```
$ awk -v OFS="\n"  '{a[NR]=$0} END {print a[4], a[5], a[1], a[2], a[3]}' file
name4
name5
name1
name2
name3
```

Or even give the order as a variable:

```
awk -v order="4 5 1 2 3" 
      'BEGIN {split(order,lines)}
       {a[NR]=$0} 
       END {for (i=1;i<=length(lines);i++) print a[lines[i]]}' file
```

If you want to give the order of the lines as an argument, you can use [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) saying `awk '...' <(command) file` and working with FNR/NR to distinguish between the input and the file

Or you can use `-` to read from stdin as first file:

```
echo "4 5 1 2 3" | awk 'FNR==NR {n=split($0,lines); next}
    {a[FNR]=$0}
    END {for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[lines[i]]}' - file
```

As one-liner:

```
$ echo "4 5 1 2 3" | awk 'FNR==NR {n=split($0,lines); next} {a[FNR]=$0} END {for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[lines[i]]}' - a
```

Comment: what if the lines weren't in a file but is just fetched by another command. can you still pipeline to the tail and head combination? :)

Comment: Better update your question with this information, together with an example, so that it is more clear. Now it sounds a bit broad.

Comment: hehe. sorry. will do. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `sort` actually:

```
$ sort -r -s -k 1.5,1.5 /tmp/lines 
line10
line11
line12
line01
line02
line03
line04
line05
line06
line07
line08
line09
```

The `-k 1.5,1.5` means I'm using only 5th character of first word for sorting. `-r` means reverse order and `-s` means stable - leaving lines that have same 5th character in the same order.

Comment: its working now. thanks! hehe. but the '-s' flag was not recognized and i tried removing it, but the lines are just in reverse order.

Comment: i've already applied the 'sort -r' in my application because i needed the line10 and line12 to be processed first. but is there another way to keep the other lines as it is?

Comment: No idea. My `man sort` doesn't mention `-s` as being something special.